# javamail with OVH and Gmail

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, jhipster, ovh

I have 2 VPS on OVH. The same Spring boot app can send mail with java mail in the first VPS and the second can't. It's the same machine, same jar.

- I launch the jar with root :
- I already active the unsecure acces in gmail : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
- I accepte the link https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuM5KYYYYYYL0iffJC4Yff3i8lLM2cb8888iWhK2QqKnUwoPp8tUfG4xljMbAZd6WApxxxxD1raE_GvP0000-QOZtemF7alt9kme8Ega9xojFquexxxxxxxx

My Spring boot conf :

```
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: xxx@gmail.com
    password: xxxx
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

the error in the second machine is :

serveur OK :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

root@xxxx:/tmp# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

serveur KO :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

the error in the second machine :

> org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication
> failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
> 534-5.7.14
> <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu
> 534-5.7.14
> M5KYYYYYYL0iffJC4Yff3i8lLM2cb8888iWhK2QqKnUwoPp8tUfG4xljMbAZd6WApxxxx
> 534-5.7.14 D1raE_GvP0000-QOZtemF7alt9kme8Ega9xojFquexxxxxxxx>
> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
> 534-5.7.14  Learn more at 534 5.7.14
> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a2sm63156wrn.68 - gsmtp
> at
> org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
> at
> org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
> at
> org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
> at fr.sadakat.api.service.MailService.sendEmail(MailService.java:141)
> at
> fr.sadakat.api.service.MailService.sendLienRecuFiscalByDonFromTemplate(MailService.java:193)
> at
> fr.sadakat.api.service.MailService.sendLienRecuFiscalByDon(MailService.java:181)
> at
> fr.sadakat.api.service.MailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7d4e9f4.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
> at
> fr.sadakat.api.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:100)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14
> <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKxxxsbu
> 534-5.7.14
> M5KmxxxxxiffJC4Yff3i8lLM2cbeQxxxxxx8tUfG4xljMbAZd6WApK3JKDzpbQ
> 534-5.7.14
> D1raE_GvPPS63F-QxxxxxxxxxxjFque9MQ3ExxxxxxxxDPg7Sjq2F>
> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
> 534-5.7.14  Learn more at 534 5.7.14
> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a2sm63156wrn.68 - gsmtp
>
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)     at
> org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
> at
> org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437)
> ... 33 common frames omitted

Comment: Have you checked that password is really the same? I mean you say you use same properties but are there in an external file that could be decoded differently on the 2nd server. Also, maybe there gmail has some restrictions on IP addresses or number of simultaneous connections, have you tried stopping first server?

Comment: there is not external conf in the second server. When the first server run, he does'nt maintain connection with google'smtp and haven't simultaneous connections